# Generating lighthouse html report using cypress

Tags: html, cypress, lighthouse

I am trying to generate the lighthouse report in html format, but am unable to do so.

I am getting the following error:

> Cannot find module 'lighthouse/lighthouse-core/report/report-generator'

I used the following link to configure my lighthouse test:-

https://atomfrede.gitlab.io/2021/04/automated-frontend-perfomance-test-with-lighthouse-for-jhipster/

Not sure, what is the error actually, I tried installing lighthouse again and again. Still, no luck.

```
npm install --save-dev lighthouse
```

This is the code I have tried:-

```
const { lighthouse, pa11y, prepareAudit } = require('cypress-audit');
const fs = require('fs');
const ReportGenerator = require('lighthouse/lighthouse-core/report/report-generator');

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('before:browser:launch', (browser, launchOptions) => {

    prepareAudit(launchOptions);
    if (browser.name === 'chrome' && browser.isHeadless) {
      launchOptions.args.push('--disable-gpu');
      return launchOptions;
    }
  });

  on('task', {
    lighthouse: lighthouse((lighthouseReport) => {
      fs.writeFileSync('build/cypress/lhreport.html', 
         ReportGenerator.generateReport(lighthouseReport.lhr, 'html'));
    }),
    pa11y: pa11y(),
  });
};
```

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue, Can some help me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 9):

At a quick glance, it looks like you missed the step to install lighthouse

From [npm - Lighthouse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lighthouse)

**Installation:**

```js
npm install -g lighthouse
# or use yarn:
# yarn global add lighthouse
```

So the above are **global** install commands - but you have used **local** install.

Not sure if global is necessary, or why, but it's the instruction given.

Comment: I installed it globally but still it didn't resolve the problem. I can see same error as above.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I followed the path to the report-generator and noticed that `"lighthouse-core"` was not in the path. This worked for me:

```
const ReportGenerator = require('lighthouse/report/generator/report-generator');
```

Comment: It didn't resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The correct path is this, it worked for me:

```
const ReportGenerator = require('lighthouse/report/generator/report-generator');
```

Answer (score 0):

Path for ReportGenerator seems to change over time, from `'lighthouse/lighthouse-core/report/report-generator'` to `'lighthouse/report/report-generator'`.

However at least in the current last `@cypress-audit/ligthouse` version `1.4.2` which depends on `lightouse` `^10.0.2`, seems that importing this way doesn't work (event changing the path). Anyway to generate the report in html is not even necessary to user `ReportGenerator` it's possible to do it configuring lighthouse output options as in [documentation explains](https://github.com/mfrachet/cypress-audit/blob/master/packages/documentation/docs/guides/lighthouse/reports.md):

In `cypress/plugins/index.js`, using `fs` save the automatically generated report:

```js
const { lighthouse, prepareAudit } = require("@cypress-audit/lighthouse");
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on("before:browser:launch", (browser = {}, launchOptions) => {
    prepareAudit(launchOptions);
  });

  on("task", {
    lighthouse: lighthouse((lighthouseReport) => {
      console.log("---- Writing lighthouse report to disk ----");

      fs.writeFile("lighthouse.html", lighthouseReport.report, (error: any) => {
        error ? console.log(error) : console.log("Report created successfully");
      });
    }),
  });
};
```

And configure the `html` as output when `cy.lighthouse` is called. This is a random configuration, the important part is the `settings: { output : "html" }` part:

```js
const thresholds = {
  "performance": 50,
  "accessibility": 50,
  "best-practices": 50,
  "seo": 50
}

const lighthouseOptions = {
  formFactor: 'desktop',
  screenEmulation: { disabled: true },
}

  const lighthouseConfig = {
  settings: { output: "html" },
  extends: "lighthouse:default",
}

cy.lighthouse(thresholds, lighthouseOptions, lighthouseConfig);
```

Additionally add the dependencies in `package.json`:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "cy:run": "cypress run --browser chrome"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "13.5.1",
    "@cypress-audit/lighthouse": "1.4.2",
  }
}
```

And add `cypress/plugins/index.js` in `cypress.config.js`:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  video: false,
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
        return require('./cypress/plugins/index.js')(on, config)
    },
  }
});
```